# Bookmarklet not working when in anchor

Tags: javascript, html

Im having trouble with creating a JS bookmarklet,

I have the following that when clicked works perfectly, only when I wrap it in anchor tags it no longer works...

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png" style="position: fixed; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; z-index: 1000">';})();
```

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work. Tell us what it does. Tell us what errors show up in the JS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move a parenthesis to the right:

```
javascript:(function(){
  document.body.innerHTML += 
   '<img src="http://www.dannemann.com/images/lensflarePhilosophy.png" '+
   'style="position: fixed; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; z-index: 1000">';}());
 //                                                                       ^moved
```